# I am building a release apk in flutter but at the end it show me this error

Tags: flutter, dart

**flutter build apk --release**

You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for `android-arm, android-arm64.`

> If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to
>   use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
>       To generate an app bundle, run:
>           flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64
>           Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
>       To split the APKs per ABI, run:
>           flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64 --split-per-abi
>           Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
>   Initializing gradle...
>   1.2s Resolving dependencies...                                           3.7s registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection) registerResGeneratingTask
>   is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use
>   registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection) Running Gradle task
>   'assembleRelease'...
>
> Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done
>   140.3s (!)
>
> Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Comment: Are you creating apk by ```flutter run --release``` or by exporting the project in android studio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```

Read [document](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#building-the-app-for-release) for more information

Answer (score 5):

Over time, android has spread throughout the world and runs on more than 2 billion devices. Because of android running on multiple platforms and foam-factors, it is very important to make sure an optimised app is installed on each platform.

For eg., a phone which doesn't have a high-resolution screen, should not get high-res images and thus reduce the size of the APK.

To make sure your app is optimized for each platform, android provides 2 methods:

1. You can split your app into multiple APKs optimized for each platform.

   `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`
2. Create an app-bundle and deploy it to play store, this way when a user downloads your app, play store automatically extracts and provides the APK which is optimized for that device.

   `flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64`

Answer (score 4):

Best way I found

```
flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
```